# Steam overlay text is missing on Linux

Tags: steam, terraria, linux

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 as my primary OS, and also installed steam on it,
2 games are installed: Stardew Valley and Terraria.

I've got one issue with the Steam overlay. Steam overlay rendered perfectly fine on Stardew Valley, but somehow rendered with no text and image on Terraria.

I've tried to check the game integrity file, but there's no issue at all. Not sure if it's a bug from Terraria or the Steam overlay itself.

I really appreciate if someone can help me with this issue, because I've never found any solution since Terraria 2.4.3 released date.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/7889) on the Steam for Linux repository, it a mix of problems in both Mesa and FNA3D which both have now been fixed.

To update FNA3D, [check this section on PCGamingWiki](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Terraria#Game_running_slowly.2Flow_frame_rate). To update mesa, [check this article by It's Foss](https://itsfoss.com/install-mesa-ubuntu/).